# What is the difference between なにかな and なんだろう?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I want to see if なにかな or なんだろう, would be used in a similar way. I asked about what would be a good chat topic and the response was なにかな. I have also seen なんだろう and jisho gives similar definitions.　Don't both terms indicate a type of wondering? I am thinking that なんだろう may be more of a surprise.

Comment: This post would be a lot more helpful to the site if you included examples of why you are asking about this.  AFAIK they can be used in similar ways, but the meaning is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なにかな is a word to tell someone.
なんだろう is a word to tell yourself.

When you are talked to by someone, you should say なにかな to him or her and you should say なんだろう to yourself.

なにかな and なんだろう means “What do you want to say?” “What is that?” “What?” “ I wonder what.”

In some Japanese TV programs, a comedian has to answer  what is in a box (It may be a snake or other animals.)
He says なんだろう. He is just saying “I wonder what’s in the box.” not particularly paying attention to people.
He also says なにかな. He is telling people there “I’m wondering what’s in the box.”

Comment: What are the meanings of both usages?

Comment: なにかな means “what do you want to say?” “what is that?” or just “what?”

Comment: what is nandarou? Include  the answers in the post.

Comment: 「なにかな」 can also mean "I wonder what..." (wondering to oneself or asking oneself), no?

Comment: You are right. なにかな is a word to make heard by someone. なんだろう is a word to make heard by yourself.

Comment: I don’t say なにかな to myself. But if you say なにかな to yourself, you probably say that to another you in your mind.