# Is the なの in 任務なのだろうか the same なの as in the linked answer, and how does the の wrap around the preceding sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension, grammar

Is the なの in the bolded 任務なのだろうか below the same なの as in the [linked answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72298/26406), and how does the の "wrap around the preceding sentence"?  Context provided below.

> 僕はラジオを点けて、空電混じりの英語のニュースに耳を傾ける。いつもならアインも黙って傍らに座り、意味の取れないフレーズに注釈をつけてくれたりするのだが、その夜は外出の支度を始めていた。珍しいことではない。時折こんな風に、アインは夜どこかへ出かけることがある。**任務なのだろうか？**

Edit: Asking this question as the なの formed at the end of sentences comes from んです／のだ but my なの isn't at the end of the sentence, thereby making me doubt it being either of the above choices. Is my nano a な with a attributive だ as shown in [this answer?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5399/26406)

Comment: 任務(だ) is working as the reason for アイン's absence, hence (な)の. You can read about this on [Wasabi](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/) and [Tofugu](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-form-ndesu/).

Comment: ～な before a noun is always the attributive form of ～だ regardless of the position in a sentence. And this の is a noun. 任務 + な + の + だろう + か.